# Selecting a table row, coloring a combobox based on item selection

Tags: python, select, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I have this table, and what I want is a few things:

[image: Table]

- When I click on a cell, I want the entire row from that cell's location to be highlighted,something white-ish, and for some function to be able to get all the values from all the columns for that row
- I have colors for all the combobox items, but I want to be able to color the combobox background with the same color as the one I chose for the selected item, the colors in `painter.fillRect()`

[image: Status]

Non-divine code:

```
import sys


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets,uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton,QTableWidget,QStyledItemDelegate

class MyQComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, scrollWidget=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyQComboBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        self.scrollWidget=scrollWidget
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)

    def wheelEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return

class StatusItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.row() == 0 :
            if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected: # highligh background if selected
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight())           
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(228, 221, 131))) # Initializing...
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 1 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(185, 183, 159))) # Not Started
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 2 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(65, 203, 53))) # Track
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 3 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(38, 121, 31))) # Track Apporval
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 4 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(31, 121, 104))) # For Solve
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 5 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(48, 216, 226))) # Solve
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 6 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(226, 167, 48))) # For GeoBuild
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 7 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(226, 142, 48))) # GeoBuild
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 8 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(243, 222, 108))) # For Rotomation
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 9 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(243, 141, 108))) # Rotomation
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 10 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(154, 76, 79))) # Waiting Assets
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 11 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(76, 112, 154))) # For Packing
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 12 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(53, 89, 201))) # Packing
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 13 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(114, 228, 118))) # Preview
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 14 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(178, 114, 228))) # Ready
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 15 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(147, 169, 236))) # For Delivery
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 16 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(81, 50, 199))) # Delivered
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 17 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(84, 95, 239))) # Approved
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 18 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(239, 84, 84))) # Cancelled
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 19 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(98, 81, 81))) # On Hold
            painter.restore()
        elif index.row() == 20 :
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(98, 1, 1))) # Got Issue
            painter.restore()
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.UI=uic.loadUi('VertigoCentral.ui', self)
        self.show()
        self.TYPE = ("UV","LD")
        self.STATUS = ("Initializing ...","Not Started","Track","Track Approval",
        "For Solving", "Solve", "For GeoBuild", "GeoBuild", "For Rotomation",
        "Rotomation","Waiting Assets",
        "For Packing", "Packing","Preview","Ready",
        "For Delivery","Delivered","Approved",
        "Cancelled","On Hold","Got Issue!")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.setFixedSize(1920, 1080)

for row in range(window.ShotTable.rowCount()):
    window.ShotTable.setRowHeight(row,36)
    scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
    frmScroll = QtWidgets.QFrame(scrollArea)
    cmbOption = MyQComboBox(frmScroll)
    Status = cmbOption
    Status.setObjectName("Status")
    for index,it in enumerate(window.STATUS):
        Status.addItem("")
        Status.setItemText(index, it)



    Status.setItemDelegate(StatusItemDelegate())
    window.ShotTable.setCellWidget(row, 5, Status)
    view = Status.view()
    view.setFixedHeight(570)

window.ShotTable.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mre] and remove all unnecessary parts (including comments or aspects that are not relevant to the question).

Comment: Done. Now what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your implementation, starting with the creation of the index widget (both the `scrollArea` and `frmScroll` parents are useless), and painting issues (calling the base `paint()` implementation will potentially paint *over* the previous `fillRect()`).

Also, since you probably need to correlate the combo with the actual model data, using an index widget is not the more appropriate choice, and you should instead use a delegate on the table that will create the combo as *editor* for the cell.

A QComboBox uses a Qt model for its contents, and these models allow setting background and foreground [*roles*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#item-roles) that automatically draw items with the specified colors, if set.

While you can just use the combo [`setItemData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setItemData) function to set the colors, since you're going to use multiple instances of the same combo class, a better solution is to use a *shared* custom model.

Then, in order to also draw the combo with the selected color, you have two possibilities: either you override its `paintEvent()` and "mimic" the default behavior by altering the palette, or you just use a specific stylesheet. For this case, I'd suggest the latter, as properly implementing the painting might be unnecessary difficult.

Finally, once the delegate for the table is implemented (by overriding its [`createEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor), [`setEditorData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#setEditorData) and [`setModelData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#setModelData) functions) and set, you must call [`openPersistentEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#openPersistentEditor) for each row of the model. For obvious reasons, whenever you need to add new rows, you must remember to call `openPersistentEditor()` again (which could be done automatically if you connect to the table's model `rowsInserted` signal).

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

StatusData = [
    ("Initializing ...", QColor(228, 221, 131)),
    ("Not Started", QColor(185, 183, 159)), 
    ("Track", QColor(65, 203, 53)), 
    ("Track Approval", QColor(38, 121, 31)), 
    ("For Solving", QColor(31, 121, 104)), 
    ("Solve", QColor(48, 216, 226)), 
    ("For GeoBuild", QColor(226, 167, 48)), 
    ("GeoBuild", QColor(226, 142, 48)), 
    ("For Rotomation", QColor(243, 222, 108)), 
    ("Rotomation", QColor(243, 141, 108)), 
    ("Waiting Assets", QColor(154, 76, 79)), 
    ("For Packing", QColor(76, 112, 154)), 
    ("Packing", QColor(53, 89, 201)), 
    ("Preview", QColor(114, 228, 118)), 
    ("Ready", QColor(178, 114, 228)), 
    ("For Delivery", QColor(147, 169, 236)), 
    ("Delivered", QColor(81, 50, 199)), 
    ("Approved", QColor(84, 95, 239)), 
    ("Cancelled", QColor(239, 84, 84)), 
    ("On Hold", QColor(98, 81, 81)), 
    ("Got Issue!", QColor(98, 1, 1)), 
]

StatusRole = Qt.UserRole + 1


def textColorForBackground(bgd):
    '''
        A simple helper function that returns a foreground color that will
        always contrast to the background.
    '''
    if isinstance(bgd, QBrush):
        bgd = bgd.color()
    r, g, b, a = bgd.getRgb()
    if (r * .3 + g * .5 + b * .1) < 100:
        return QColor(Qt.white)
    return QColor(Qt.black)


class MyQComboBox(QComboBox):
    _model = None # a single model shared between instances
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self._model:
            self.__class__._model = QStandardItemModel(0, 1)
            for row, (text, color) in enumerate(StatusData):
                item = QStandardItem(text)
                item.setData(color, Qt.BackgroundRole)
                item.setData(textColorForBackground(color), Qt.ForegroundRole)
                self._model.appendRow(item)
        self.setModel(self._model)

        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateBackground)
        self.updateBackground(self.currentIndex())

    def updateBackground(self, index):
        if index < 0:
            self.setStyleSheet('')
            return
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            MyQComboBox {{
                color: {foreground};
                background: {background};
            }}
        '''.format(
            foreground=self.itemData(index, Qt.ForegroundRole).name(), 
            background=self.itemData(index, Qt.BackgroundRole).name()
        ))

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        return

    def showPopup(self):
        maxHeight = min(
            s.availableGeometry().height() for s in QApplication.screens())
        view = self.view()
        model = view.model()
        margins = view.parent().contentsMargins()
        spacing = view.spacing()
        heightHint = margins.top() + margins.bottom() - spacing
        for row in range(self.count()):
            itemHeight = view.visualRect(model.index(row, 0)).height() + spacing
            if heightHint + itemHeight > maxHeight:
                break
            heightHint += itemHeight
        view.parent().setFixedHeight(heightHint)
        super().showPopup()


class StatusDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        def updateModel(comboIndex):
            current = pIndex.data(StatusRole) or 0
            if comboIndex != current:
                self.commitData.emit(editor)

        pIndex = QPersistentModelIndex(index)
        editor = MyQComboBox(parent)
        editor.clearFocus()
        editor.currentIndexChanged.connect(updateModel)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        statusIndex = index.data(StatusRole)
        if (
            statusIndex is not None
            and editor.currentIndex() != statusIndex
        ):
            editor.setCurrentIndex(statusIndex)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        current = index.data(StatusRole) or 0
        editorIndex = editor.currentIndex()
        if editorIndex != current:
            model.setData(index, editorIndex, StatusRole)
            if editorIndex > 0:
                background = editor.itemData(editorIndex, Qt.BackgroundRole)
            else:
                background = None
            model.setData(index, background, Qt.BackgroundRole)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.UI=uic.loadUi('VertigoCentral.ui', self)

        self.ShotTable.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.ShotTable.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(36)
        self.ShotTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            5, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ShotTable.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            5, StatusDelegate(self.ShotTable))

        for row in range(self.ShotTable.rowCount()):
            item = self.ShotTable.item(row, 5)
            if not item:
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                self.ShotTable.setItem(row, 5, item)
            self.ShotTable.openPersistentEditor(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: How can I subclass the Table that I'm using from the UI file ?

Comment: @CollegiaTitanica Do some research on promoted widgets.